# Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org".Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds… (10 tries left)

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build, dart-pub

Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". Error (69): Unable to 'pub upgrade' flutter tool. Retrying in five seconds... (10 tries left)

that is the error in flutter when i create or upgrade flutter:

> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.
>
> Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6
>
> PS E:\Flutter WorkSpace\Flutter Projects> flutter create sampleproject
> Recreating project sampleproject... Running "flutter pub get" in
> sampleproject... Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". pub
> get failed (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...
> Could not resolve URL "https://pub.dartlang.org". pub get failed
> (server unavailable) -- attempting retry 2 in 2 seconds... Running
> "flutter pub get" in sampleproject...                   (This is
> taking an unexpectedly long time.)

Comment: Try re-installing from source or ```flutter version <enter version you wanted>```

Comment: The answer is not clear @JohnMelodyMelissa

Comment: I mean You either have to delete your current flutter directory , and build it from the flutter source or alternatively just do a ```flutter version <enter version you wanted>``` in the terminal and see what happens.

Comment: I need to know more of the issue was raised and the what had you tried or did which caused the issue.

Comment: The actual issue is that,Im trying to build my first flutter project,I create the project via terminal ,I put the command flutter create project_name,while building ,they couldn't complete the build.They couldn't get all the packages.Build failed.@JohnMelodyMelissa

Comment: @SruthiMariaThomson This thread might help. Have a look - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12666

Comment: Did you declare PATH variable? Is your flutter install correctly? Refer the tutorial here : https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install

Comment: Yes I already set the path variable.@JohnMelodyMelissa

Comment: Yes I solved my issue Thanks@JohnMelodyMelissa

Answer (score 2):

Try to use from some VPN connection for your system.

This issue happens when server does not reachable.

Second way : Use google DNS for your connection :

primary : 8.8.8.8

secondary : 8.8.4.4